# Tomcat websocket TEXT_FULL_WRITING

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket, synchronization, illegalstateexception

In Tomcat 8.5.9, session.getAsyncRemote().sendText() method throws

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The remote endpoint was in state
>   [TEXT_FULL_WRITING]

I created a mutex acquired before calls to send methods and released after the call:

```
 sendMutex.acquireUninterruptibly();
    try{
      session.getAsyncRemote().sendText(gson.toJson(message));
    }catch(Exception exception){
      logger.error("Session : "+session.getId()+" message : "+gson.toJson(message)+" exception : "+exception.getMessage(),exception);
    }
    sendMutex.release();
```

But exception is still thrown when this method is called. There are no calls to 
session.getAsyncRemote().sendText() or session.getBasicRemote().sendText() other than this method. ServerEndpoint returns void in onMessage method.

Thanks

Comment: I found the answer in a forum. Until the future of async call is complete new sendText calls throw llegalStateException.

Comment: Thanks for this, how did you check the status of the future of async call in order to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Been having the same issue.
I found this solution to work, seems not to create other problems.

```
this.session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(message);
```

instead of using

```
this.session.getAsyncRemote().sendObject(message);
```

Apparently this is a common issue with tomcat, and the way a websocket session instance can be accessed from different threads at the same times.

```
synchronized(ep)
    {
        this.session.getAsyncRemote().sendObject(message);
    }
```

where ep is a static object, that did not work either in my experience.